# Swift: Array of objects that conforms to same protocol as the object

Tags: swift, generics

I have a question about generics in swift.

First of all, In `JSONDecoder` we have the below `function`.

```
func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T where T : Decodable
```

And assuming we have a struct called `Book: Codable` defined before, we can call this function as;

```
decoder.decode(Book.self, from: bookData)
```

and also as;

```
decoder.decode([Book].self, from: bookListData)
```

We were able to feed the function with the array of `Book` objects, however as far I know `[Book].self` does not conform to `Decodable`.

My question how can we apply a similar solution, when we try to feed a generic `struct` or `class` instead of a function. For example,

```
protocol Publishable { /* literally empty */ }

class Manager<T: Publishable> {
   var data: T?

   // managing stuff
}
```

we have the above `Manager` class and an extesion as, `extension Book: Publishable`. we can create an instance from it like,

```
let bookManager = Manager<Book>()
```

But we cannot directly say,

```
let bookListManager = Manager<[Book]>()
```

Let me tell you, I am not sure how the first examples even works. I didn't realize it until I have faced this problem. Anyway, I am looking for a solution or an advice that may enable me to create an instance as above. Or any other way.

Appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I am aware of a solution where I could create another struct as,

```
struct BookList: Publishable {
   var books: [Book]
}
```

and then,

```
let bookListManager = Manager<BookList>()
```

will work. However, It would require me to create ton of middle structures which would be inconvenient.

Comment: `let bookListManager = Manager<[Book]>()` works for me. Please edit your question and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Edited. @LeoDabus

Comment: I am still not sure what is your issue. Show your `Book` declaration. Now your generic type doesn't require to be `Decodable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as far I know [Book].self does not conform to Decodable

[It does.](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Codable.swift) (Actually, that's `[Book]`, not `[Book].Type`, but `[Book].self` isn't what you meant.)

```swift
extension Array: Decodable where Element: Decodable { …
```

If you want similar functionality, extend similarly.

```swift
extension Array: Publishable where Element: Publishable { }
```

Comment: thanks for your response. directly implemented the second line and obviously it is working. I was searching how `[Decodable].self` conforms to `Decodable` could not find anything, probably my fault though. @Jessy